# how to send a request to google home\assistant like IFTTT+webhooks

Tags: google-home, google-assistant-sdk

Please direct me the right way. I'm stuck with some documentation issue. Going to code a small service with Google HOME for everyone to add a new phrase and make a POST request or answer with specific "TEXT" (like IFTTT run with WEBHOOKS) (fe: "Hey Google switch my kitchen light" -> service will send POST request to my own HTTP server). I know that IFTTT works but - I would to code the target service for tiny cases with fast response.

I tried to understand all Google Assistant layers - but still no luck and didn't find the clear path.

What I learned are: 
1. connect to Google Account using OAuth 2 
2. .... save the phrase and action for that in my DB - it's ok and simple way 
3. ...??? how to send and to where? in (json?) a specific format 
4. receive the answer from google home to understand the right case and make my action.... (for example: turn on\off the kitchen light)

It should be not so hard as I can image.... anyway Please help :).

Appreciate your time and answers and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

To learn about extending the Google Assistant, you should look into the documentation for Actions on Google: https://developers.google.com/actions/extending-the-assistant

Although it also seems like you want to use it for Smart Home: https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/

You can run the Smart Home sample if you want to see how it works: https://github.com/actions-on-google/actionssdk-smart-home-nodejs

Comment: i'm NOT saying about APPLICATION  inside Google Assistant as device \ smarthome. I'm trying to: 


1. create a new online service for any user 


2. link Google Account using OAuth 2 2.


3. access to Google HOME API 



4. create a new case like: "IF I SAY 'bla-bla-bla' - send POST to `http://......`"


using https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ you can try - but, I can't found the GOOGLE HOME (ASSISTANT) API

Comment: What you want does not exist. There is a 3P platform, Actions on Google. For Smart Home applications you can do a single line command like "turn on the lights". There is an Assistant SDK but that is only for embedding it into your own iot device.

Comment: ok - but HOW IFTTT works with "say something" google assistant :D - it's really interesting.

Comment: It's a special integration. You could also use the Shortcuts settings in the Google Assistant to set a single statement doing a longer command, although that is not universal.

Comment: thanks ! I wanna create a service for USERS not just only for me :) - I used IFTTT for my home controlling locally - and yes - its work fine!. But now, I want to provide a free and open service for users who do not want to create IFTTT account and understand a lot of applets.... easy to use - type and get - what I want )

as I can see and you proved my thoughts - IFTTT has a special GOOGLE-IFTTT integration :D - will try to ask Google how I can do the same :]

Comment: Alex, were you able to figure this out? Contact me via the link in my profile. Нам надо поговорить.